# Planning my first SharePoint 2013 Wiki site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, wiki

I want to start my first SP2013 project, and for the first release I need to build a knowledge base library for my company. I am planning to have the following general implementation steps, and I would like to share in case I am going in the wrong road:-

1. On my Development environment, I am going to create a new Publishing site.
2. Then inside my publishing site I am going to create 5 separate “Enterprise Wikis” site collection.
3. Each of the enterprise Wiki site represents a department. so I will have an enterprise wiki site for the HR dept,  another one for the legal dept and so on. But all under the main publishing site.
4. I am going to be the administrator for the whole publishing site.
5. For each department I am going to give the employees who are under the department a “contribute” privilege so that they can read, view, add wikis. While the will give other employees “read” privileges.
6. For some departments such as legal; the department manager asks that he need to approve any wiki before being published. So for these department I will give the department manager the “Approve” privilege and will remove the “approve” privileges from other.
7. For the legal department I will specify that the wiki” Require content approval”.
8. After finalizing and testing my new publishing site on the Dev environment, I am going to do a back-up for the whole site and create a .wsp and move it to the production environment which will be linked to an active directory.

So based on the above I have the following questions:-

1. Will the above GENERAL 8 steps be valid to achieve my first set of requirements for building an enterprise knowledge library?
2. There are some restrictions which I want to have but I cannot figure out if they are available out of the box in SP 2013:-

   - To make the wiki taxonomy more controlled; how I can restrict creating new categories to only specified users (mainly senior staff).
   - Preventing deleting a Wiki unless you are the creator or the Admin

Thanks in advance for any help and sorry for t eh long email.

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an architectural view I see no major error, but from a user perspective the legal department wiki, is dead wrong. It's not a real wiki, since evary edit need an approval from "management". The legal department will lose the benefits of a real wiki and the joy of contributing as a whole if all they do will be "managed".

Either step up to your customer and explain what a Wiki really is and how it should be implemented. Or let the legal department be without knowledge base wiki if they can't handle it the right way.

It takes courage, but if you think your legal department users are worth a real knowledge sharing platform - this is the way to go.